# Similar elements without interfering

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the thing:

I want a **jQuery** function that allows me to append a fixed popUp, when either:

- **A.)** a mouseenter occurs, after which the popUp fades out on a following mouseleave and is deleted, or;
- **B.)** when it is specifically called for by some script, after which it fades out after a specified time and is deleted.

Shouldn't be too hard, I figured. However, because there is a fadeIn/Out() involved, it is possible that a creation of another popUp is called, before the first one has truly disappeared, making the whole thing mess up in various ways. So the question: **How can I design a function that creates and manages its created elements without confusing them?**

Now, I figured I'd add a variable ID-value to the ID of the popUps that are appended, so that the fadeIn/Out calls only apply to the correct ones, but this does not work as I intend, because when the var is increased by **var++;** the function will never manipulate a popUp with a lower ID value than that var.

So far, I've created something of the following format, which I hope Illustrates properly what I'm thinking of:

```
var p1 = 0;
var p2 = 0;

function popUp(text, duration, targetLMN){

    if (duration  && !(targetLMN)) {

        $('body').append('<div id="popUpDur_'+p1+'" class="popUp" style="display:none;"> text </div>');

        // the following lines mess up as soon as another
        // popUp is created before the last one is gone.

        $('.popUpDur_'+p1).fadeIn(t).delay(duration).fadeOut(t, function(){
            $('.popUpDur_'+p1).remove();
        });

        p1++;
    }

    else if (targetLMN && !(duration)){

        $(targetLMN).mouseenter(function(){
            $('body').append('<div id="popUpTar_'+p2+'" class="popUp" style="display:none;"> text </div>');
            $('#popUpTar_'+p2).fadeIn(t);
        });

        $(targetLMN).mouseleave(function(){
            $('#popUpTar_'+p2).fadeOut(t, function(){
                $('#popUpTar_'+p2).remove();
            });
        });

        p2++;
    }
}
```

I just can't figure it out!

Thanks in advance, SO!

Comment: they don't need unique classes/id's, you can reference the one you're currently working with by `$(this)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than generating id's/classes to select by, just keep a reference to the element.

```
// simplified example
var myEl = $("<div></div>").appendTo("body");
myEl.fadeIn(2000).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000,function(){
    myEl.remove();
});
```

Comment: Makes sense. However, won't this mess up when a new popUp is created by the 'mouseenter method', instead of by the 'duration method'?

Comment: No, because neither have access to the same `myEl`. by writing it in this way, they are completely independent of each other, and of each instance.

Comment: The duration method works fine this way, indeed. However the mouseenter popUp won't go away..!

Comment: can you make a pastebin of your current code after applying my idea?

Comment: Disregard that last comment: I did not declare the myEl correctly, so the mouseleave did not have access to it.

It works! thanks a million!

Comment: No it doesn't XD! I take back that disregard! Here's a JSF to show you what happens. It speaks for itself. http://jsfiddle.net/W9HSG/1/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38917/discussion-between-victor-and-kevin-b)